# How to add a tpl file to a block from a custom module

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have a custom module that build a block. I'm trying to add a tpl file, but I don't get nothing.
This is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 *
 * This hook declares what blocks are provided by the module.
 */
function tados2_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['block_with_tpl'] = array(
    // info: The name of the block.
    'info' => t('Tados2 example: block with tpl'),
    'status' => TRUE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * This hook generates the contents of the blocks themselves.
 */
function tados2_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case'block_with_tpl':
      // The subject is displayed at the top of the block. Note that it
      // should be passed through t() for translation. The title configured
      // for the block using Drupal UI supercedes this one.
      $block['subject'] = t('Tados2 block with tpl');
      // The content of the block is typically generated by calling a custom
      // function.
      $block['content'] = t('Hola mundo');//_tados2_block_with_tpl_contents();
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}
?>
```

I'm trying to move the content to a tpl.php file.

This what I'm trying:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Implementen hook_theme
 *
 */
function tados2_theme(){
  return array(
    'tados2_block' => array(
      //'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'tados2_block',
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL, 'content' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
/**
 * preprocess function
 * 
 */ 
function template_preprocess_tados2_block(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call your theming function:

```
$block['content'] = theme('tados2_block', array('title' => 'foo', 'content' => 'bar'));
```

Comment: Hello Leni,Thanks it will only for the content. 
For the title will be the same?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to use a template file in my block. This is my solution.

- Fist step: You need to register your theme. Use the following code in yourmodule.module.

  ```
  function yourmodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
      'yourmodule_block' => array(
        'template' => 'yourmodule',
        'variables'=> array('var1' => NULL, 'var2' => NULL),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

  Note that in `'template' => 'yourmodule'` 'yourmodule' is the template filename in your module folder.
  Check [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) for more details.
- Secondnd step: Use your theme for a block.

  ```
  function yourmodule_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch ($delta) {
      case 'yourmodule_block':
        $block['subject'] = 'LinhNH-Training';
        $block['content']['yourmodule'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'yourmodule_block',
          '#var1' => 'Module Title',
          '#var2'=>'Content '
        );

        return $block;
        break;
    }

    // return $block;
  }
  ```